# how to write to an existing excel sheet using pandas xlsxwriter engine

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, xlsxwriter

I have an excelworkbook say with name slide1 and it has one sheet Sheet1
and it already has one pandas dataframe.

Now I want to write another dataframe to the Sheet1 of slide1 workbook, but it seems to be replacing the old data from the sheet.

Comment: What have you tried so far? [How to ask.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: okay presently I was trying to use the xlsxwriter engine to open up the workbook and append the dataframe from a particular index which is after the first frame.  

So instead I tried opening up the file and then writing the frame one after another.


So I think this is the limitation of xlsxwriter rather than of pandas.